# SQL Order by column with 0 as exception

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have columns:

```
CAT  | Val
------------
none | 0
high | 5
low  | 100
med  | 50
```

as you can see, a low number is category high. (inverse logic) except for 0..

So I want to order by, so that I get the correct order for category. (none, low, med, high).

**I want them in order:**

```
CAT  | Val
------------
none | 0
low  | 100
med  | 50
high | 5
```

I tried this, but it unions, and then orders by. Brackets around each select causes error.

```
SELECT cat,  an_int FROM CATS WHERE an_int = 0
UNION
SELECT cat, an_int FROM CATS WHERE an_int <> 0 ORDER BY an_int DESC
```

This gives:

```
CAT  | Val
------------
low  | 100
med  | 50
high | 5
none | 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
select * from CATS 
order by case when cat='none' then 0 else 1 end ,Val desc
```

Comment: @Doomsknight: In this solution we dont have to read the table twice, I think this is the most effient way you can do it

Comment: Aye, I just realised. I'm trying to get this working on the integer field where = 0. There are two 0 fields, so using cat='none' wouldnt be sufficient. Sorry I ommitted this from Q. Didnt think it would be an issue. Plus the text is changeable by user. It just says Error though.

Comment: I added your case statement into the select part. Then ordered by it. `SELECT *, (CASE WHEN an_int = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as ord FROM CATS
ORDER BY ord, an_int DESC `  sqlite didnt seem happy with the case statment within the order by clause. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use another element to order by like this :

```
SELECT codepro,  nr_cpl, 1 as c FROM reservoirs WHERE nr_cpl = 0 
UNION
SELECT codepro,  nr_cpl, 2 as c FROM reservoirs WHERE nr_cpl <> 0
          order by c asc, nr_cpl desc
```

It should do the trick.